# Time series (or Survival) analysis looking at effect of multiple policy changes over time

Tags: r, time-series, survival, repeated-measures, intervention-analysis

I'd like to look at the effect of lockdown policies(announcements) over time on features of the COVID-19 epidemic. I'm not very familiar with different time-series, so i'd like advice on what type of analysis might be appropriate here. Some information about the data:

- Outcome/Dependent Variable is continuous, but does not change at regular intervals. For example, it may stay constant and then abruptly change on specific dates.
- Each region has implemented multiple government responses in the form of lockdowns. The announcement of these lockdowns does not occur at regular intervals.
- Each instance of a government policy in regards to lockdowns can increase restrictions or decrease restrictions, so we would hypothesize an increase/decrease depending on the policy towards lockdowns.

Here's a picture of what the data might look like in a hypothetical region (in reality, i'd be doing this separately for many regions).

[image]

Some questions i'd like to answer:

1. What is the average time from a lockdown policy/announcement to a change in the outcome? Perhaps this question lends itself to some kind of survival analysis?
2. What is the magnitude of that change, on average?

Comment: Survival analysis is appropriate when you want to investigate the times until events of one or several specific types. With a continuous outcome survival analysis won't be useful.

Comment: I figured survival might not be very useful here, but the part where I thought it might work is in searching for the median time to the change in outcome after a lockdown announcement is made.